# What is the equivalent of NSString stringWithFormat in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: objective-c, azure, push-notification, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub

I am using Azure Notification Hubs to send notifications. I want these notifications to be multilingual but i cannot find the equivalent of

```
NSString* jsontemplate= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"aps\":
{\"alert\":\"$(News_%@)\"},\"inAppMessage\":\"$(News_%@)\"}",
localeString, localeString];
```

to use in the function

```
Hub.RegisterTemplateAsync(deviceToken,name,jsontemplate,expirytemplate,tags, 
(errorCallback) => {
  if (errorCallback != null)
    Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " +  errorCallback.ToString());                });
```

which will substitute the function Hub.RegisterNativeAsync in the below code snippet i have now which works fine for simple notifications.

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication     application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        Hub = new SBNotificationHub(TnOConstants.AzureListenConnectionString, TnOConstants.AzureNotificationHubName);

        Hub.UnregisterAllAsync (deviceToken, (error) => {
            if (error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error.ToString());
                return;
            }

            string[] tag = new string[]{"tnoios", "ios-"+ appVersion.ToString()};

            NSSet tags = new NSSet(tag);
            Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) => {
                if (errorCallback != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
            });
        });
    }
```

I am following this tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-send-localized-breaking-news/

Comment: If you're using C# then the equivalent is `string.Format("{0}{1}", firstArg, secondArg);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The teplate i ended up using with String.Format() as the equivalent to NSString stringWithFormat to the above phraze is:

```
string template = String.Format(@"{""aps"":{""alert"":""$({0})""}}", localeString);
```